# Случайный набор чисел в массиве

Tags: javascript

Хочу понять как работает код ниже.

Что значит вернуть Math.random() - 0.5

Как я понимаю Matn.random() возвращает случайное число

от 0 до 1. Но как он здесь работает?
Тут же числа больше 1.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  array.sort(function(){
    return Math.random() - 0.5;  // - 0.5 что это?
  }) 
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];             // числа больше 1 и 0.
shuffle(arr);
alert(arr);
```

Comment: А как должно влиять то, что в массиве числа больше 0 и 1 на то, что написано в функции сортировки, 
 если они  у вас никак не участвуют в сравнении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило, функция сортировки работает с элементами массива, учитывает их значения, поэтому ваше замешательство тут понятно. Однако именно в этом случае для функции сортировки всё равно, что там в массиве — большие числа, маленькие, строки или что-то другое. Её задание просто перемешать элементы в случайном порядке. Поэтому она должна в случайном порядке возвращать то любое отрицательное число, то любое положительное. Число `0.5` как раз находится посередине набора всех чисел, которые может вернуть `Math.random()`. Поэтому `Math.random() - 0.5` будет как раз в случайном порядке возвращать то небольшое отрицательное число, то небольшое положительное: если `Math.random()` даст число больше `0.5`, то вычитание вернёт положительное число, если меньше — отрицательное.

Comment: Но как Math.random() возвращает числа больше единицы? Он ведь должен возвращать числа с плавающей точкой не больше 1, то есть например 0.3232 и т.д.

Comment: "Но как Math.random() возвращает числа больше единицы" - Никак. Почему Вы решили, что он это делает?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что `Math.random()` тут возвращает числа больше единицы? Функция сортировки просто должна возвращать положительные и отрицательные числа, им не обязательно быть больше единицы.

Comment: Про метод sort() мне понятно, он меняет порядок элементов в массиве. Я не могу понять, как тут работает math.random().

Comment: `Math.random()` возвращает число или чуть меньше 0.5 или чуть больше 0.5. Этого хватает, чтобы при вычитании 0.5 получалось или положительное число от 0 до 0.5 или отрицательное от -0.5 до 0. Этого достаточно, чтобы функция сортировки перемешивала элементы, независимо от самих элементов (как вы видите, в функции даже не используются традиционные аргументы `a` и `b` для сравнения элементов).

Comment: Потом это число прибавляется к элементам сортировки и отсюда уже идет случайная перемешка?

Comment: Нет, к элементам сортировки ничего не прибавляется. Это такая хитрость, хак, если хотите: самого этого числа от вычитания достаточно, чтобы элементы случайно сортировались.

Comment: Нет. Сортируемые числа никак не меняются. Случайным образом вычисляется результат их сравнения.

Comment: @Человек `Math.random()` дает случайные числа в интервале `[0, 1)` и если из всех этих чисел всегда отнимать 0.5 - будут получаться числа в интервале `[-0.5, 0.5)` — а sort решает, в каком порядке поставить сравниваемую пару элементов массива - в зависимсти от того, вернула функция положительное число или отрицательное. А т.к. числа случайные - и сортировка получается случайной.

Comment: Числа в интервале -0.5, 0.5 как они взаимодействуют с sort? 
Тут же у меня идет сравнение чисел 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Может, вам так будет понятнее: элементы массива для функции сортировки тут как чёрные ящики, она их не видит. Она как бы подбрасывает монетку: если орёл (то есть `Math.random() - 0.5` дало больше нуля) — передвигает ящик выше, если решка (то есть `Math.random() - 0.5` дало меньше нуля) — передвигает ниже. Содержимое ящиков не меняется, и функция о них не знает.

Comment: @Человек Вы уже прочитали документацию по ссылке в моем ответе?

Comment: @Igor, там ничего не понятно. То, что я ищу там нет((